# Can mark be extended outside checkbox in JavaFX using CSS?

Tags: java, css, checkbox, javafx

I want to make a custom checkbox, but my mark is limited by box size. Is there a way to extend it outside bounds?

CSS code for checkbox:

```
.check-box{
-fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
-fx-font-size: 18;
-fx-text-fill:#01449f;}

.check-box .box{
-fx-outer-border: #cadbec;
-fx-body-color: white;
 -fx-background-color: 
   -fx-outer-border, 
   -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
-fx-background-radius: 2px, 0px;}

.check-box .mark {
-fx-shape:"M14.596,2.055L12.455,0C9.687,2.884,6.011,6.714,5.158,7.602L2.055,4.624L0,6.765l5.242,5.037l0.003-0.004
l0.003,0.004L14.596,2.055z";}

.check-box:selected .mark {
-fx-background-color: #0181e2;}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can scale the graphic:

```
.check-box .mark {
    -fx-shape:"M14.596,2.055L12.455,0C9.687,2.884,6.011,6.714,5.158,7.602L2.055,4.624L0,6.765l5.242,5.037l0.003-0.004
    l0.003,0.004L14.596,2.055z";
    -fx-scale-x: 2;
    -fx-scale-y: 2;
}
```

[image: Check]

**EDIT**

To move the tick, you can translate it:

```
.check-box .mark {
      -fx-shape:"M14.596,2.055L12.455,0C9.687,2.884,6.011,6.714,5.158,7.602L2.055,4.624L0,6.765l5.242,5.037l0.003-0.004
    l0.003,0.004L14.596,2.055z";
    -fx-scale-x: 2;
    -fx-scale-y: 2;
    -fx-translate-x: 5px;
    -fx-translate-y: -3px;
}
```

[image: CheckBox]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to move mark 3px to top and 5px to right?